# Typed Racket convert Any to All (a)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, typed-racket, typed

I'm trying to call `take` on the output of `flatten`. The problem is that `take` requires a list of `a` but `flatten` returns a list of `Any`. Is there a way to convert between them? Or some other approach I'm supposed to take? I wasn't able to find any examples in the Racket Docs.

```
(: extend (All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer (Listof a))))               
(define (extend l n)                                 
  ; extend a list to length 'n' by appending it to itself           
  ;                                                        
  ; @l        list of any                                         
  ; @n        int                                              
  ; @return   list of any 

  (take (flatten (make-list n l)) n))
```

From the interpreter, here are the exact types for each function for reference.

```
 > take                
 - : (All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer (Listof a)))       
 #<procedure:take> 

 > flatten             
 - : (-> Any (Listof Any))
 #<procedure:flatten>
```

Here's the error message for reference too.

```
alg/waterfall.rkt:65:2: Type Checker: Polymorphic function `take' could not be applied to arguments:                                                                         
Argument 1:                                                                 
  Expected: (Listof a)                                                      
  Given:    (Listof Any)                                                    
Argument 2:                                                                 
  Expected: Integer                                                         
  Given:    Integer                                                         

Result type:     (Listof a)                                                 
Expected result: (Listof a)
```

Comment: The trouble here is that `flatten` is really hard to give a precise type, since it flattens lists of arbitrary depth. Consider using `append*` here, instead; it does a simpler thing and therefore has a nicer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alexis King is right. The `flatten` function has more complicated behavior that doesn't fit with the type you need. The `append*` function is simpler, and here it's actually what you need instead of `flatten`.

In the place where you use it:

```
; n : Integer
; l : (Listof a)
(take (flatten (make-list n l)) n)
; expected type: (Listof a)
```

The input to `flatten` is a `(Listof (Listof a))`, and for it to typecheck the output must be a `(Listof a)`. This has to be true **even when `a` includes lists**.

The function you want is something with the type `(Listof (Listof a)) -> (Listof a)`. Now, does `flatten` always have that type? No it can't, here's a counterexample:

```
a = (Listof Integer)
input : (Listof (Listof (Listof Integer)))
input = (list (list (list 1)))
expected output type: (Listof (Listof Integer))
actual output value:  (list 1)
```

Therefore `flatten` cannot have the type `(Listof (Listof a)) -> (Listof a)`. What you need is `append*`, which does have that type.

```
> append*
- : (All (a) (-> (Listof (Listof a)) (Listof a)))
#<procedure:append*>
```

In your example, you can use `append*` where you used `flatten`.

```
(: extend (All (a) (-> (Listof a) Integer (Listof a))))               
(define (extend l n)                                 
  ; extend a list to length 'n' by appending it to itself           
  ;                                                        
  ; @l        list of any                                         
  ; @n        int                                              
  ; @return   list of any 

  (take (append* (make-list n l)) n))
```